# ReferenceError: Property '_updatePropsPaper' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

***I'm facing this error while using Reanimated 2.***

- I'm using `"react-native": "0.70.1"`
- `"react-native-reanimated": "^3.0.0-rc.3"`

I added this code in

> babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};
```

I already tried `yarn start --reset-cache`. But it didn't work out!

[image]

Comment: "I'm facing this error while using Reanimated 2" -- But you import v3. Can you clarify that?

Comment: Actually, this is the @next version

Comment: I am also getting this. Were you able to fix this?

Comment: opened an issue here.
If you have more info please add. 
https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3806